# Weird "Package could not be found" problem

Tags: java, macos, package

Essentially I've got a problem where in OS X packages are not recognised in Java, ever. I've tried on numerous occasions to use packages and they never work. I know I'm doing it right because the same packages work absolutely fine on Windows. Does anyone know what my problem could be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't accepted ANY answers! Please accept at least a few.

Comment: Unless you show us what you are working with, we will just be guessing.

Comment: Please give a sequence of commands and their output.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using lowercase names for both the package name and the folder name corresponding to it?

Comment: @Jeff: Windows has a case-insensitive file system, so an error on that part would be tolerated on Windows.

Comment: The windows file system is case-insensitive, that's why I was asking.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. Thats  interesting to know for the future anyway!